# Get DB table from json array with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have the following record in my database where I have to get all records containing any of the records.

Table record contains:
$record_ids = ["123","234","111"]

Trying to search for it like the following with Laravel:

```
$records = DB::table('records_table')
  ->where('id', $id)
  ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(record_id, ?)', $record_ids)
  ->pluck('records');
```

I've also tried with similar solutions like:

```
->whereIn('record_id', $record_ids)
```

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and Mysql.

Update:
It works when I 'manually' add it like the following:

```
->whereIn('record_id', ["123","234","111"])
```

But when fetching the array from the database it doesn't work

Comment: What type of column is `record_id`?

Comment: It's a JSON table (Have tried changing to text also).

Comment: Are the values in the JSON array integers or strings?

Comment: Wait sorry, my mistake! The record_id is a integer array

Comment: You want to find the rows where the `record_id` column contains *all* the ids from `$record_ids`?

Comment: Exactly! So where the array for record_id is 123, 234 or 111 in this case.

Comment: You wrote "or": Should the column contain 123 *or* 234 *or* 111? Or 123 *and* 234 *and* 111?

Comment: Should be _and_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use here:

```
->whereIn('record_id', json_decode($json, true));
```

Comment: Yes! That worked! I tried something similar and the issue was in the code above so the result didn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The types have to match (integer vs. string) and the search value has to be JSON encoded:

```
$search = json_encode(array_map('intval', $record_ids));

$records = DB::table('records_table')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(record_id, ?)', $search)
    ->pluck('records');
```

In Laravel 5.6, you can use [`whereJsonContains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses):

```
->whereJsonContains('record_id', array_map('intval', $record_ids));
```